# How to delete read more span on single post view?

Tags: templates, single, read-more

How could I complete delete following line on single post view?

```
<p><span id="more-XXX"></span></p>
```

I need to delete whole span tag. Is there any other option than preg_replace?

Comment: You should just need to delete it from your templates. If you're working with a child theme then you should ask the developer of the parent theme.

Comment: But this span is "added by" and "returned in" WP the_content() function. This not a feature of template.

Comment: Oh right. Are you using the Read More tag in the editor? Is this causing a problem? It's there so that users can jump to the part they left off at from the index views.

Comment: Yes, I am using Read More tag. I am writing my own theme and I just have to delete this span on single post view.

Comment: Removing this should really be up to the user, because it's standard WordPress functionality. It's not a decision a theme should be making. If it's causing display issues then the problem is with your CSS.

Comment: I am the only one user of this theme ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [in the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/), if the quicktag `<!--more-->` is used in a post to designate the “cut-off” point for the post to be excerpted, `the_content()` tag will only show the excerpt up to the `<!--more-->` quicktag point on non-single/non-permalink post pages.

WordPress adds `<span id="more-' . $post->ID . '"></span>` to the content in this case. Since there's no content in the `<span>` ([check out the code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/)), you can easily remove the `<span>` by filtering the content:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
  return str_replace( '<span id="more-' . get_the_ID() . '"></span>', '', $content );
}
```

Note that this causes the Read More link not to jump to the area where you inserted `<!--more-->` anymore. An easier way to achieve this would be to use the [`the_content_more_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content_more_link/) filter and remove the `#more-<post_id>` part from it there. There are a few [examples in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More) for that.